# How to convert an array of objects into an object of specific format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, antd

I have been struggling with a problem that I am trying to solve in a performant and better way. Basically I have a Collection, or in simpler terms an array of objects. I'll paste the collection down:

```
[
    {
      "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw",
      "pluginVersion": 1,
      "pcVersion": "4.26",
      "platform": "win",
      "previews": [
        {
          "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip"
    },
    {
      "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw",
      "pluginVersion": 1,
      "pcVersion": "4.26",
      "platform": "mac",
      "previews": [
        {
          "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip"
    },
    {
      "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw",
      "pluginVersion": 1,
      "pcVersion": "4.26",
      "platform": "linux",
      "previews": [
        {
          "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip"
    },
    {
      "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw1",
      "pluginVersion": 1,
      "pcVersion": "4.26",
      "platform": "win",
      "previews": [
        {
          "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip"
    },
    {
      "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw1",
      "pluginVersion": 1,
      "pcVersion": "4.26",
      "platform": "mac",
      "previews": [
        {
          "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip"
    },
    {
      "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw1",
      "pluginVersion": 1,
      "pcVersion": "4.26",
      "platform": "linux",
      "previews": [
        {
          "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip"
    },
    {
      "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw2",
      "pluginVersion": 1,
      "pcVersion": "4.26",
      "platform": "win",
      "previews": [
        {
          "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip"
    }
  ]
```

Now the reason that I want to change it a specific format is that I could use it with a UI library that dictates it to be in a specific format. I'll paste the end result down:

```
[
{
    "name": "fy9h-dKw", "children": [
        {
            "name": "4.26", "children": [
                {
                    "name": "1", "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "mac", "children": [
                                {
                                    "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw",
                                    "pluginVersion": 1,
                                    "pcVersion": "4.26",
                                    "platform": "mac",
                                    "previews": [
                                        {
                                            "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip"
                                }
                            ],
                            "name": "windows", "children": [
                                {
                                    "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw",
                                    "pluginVersion": 1,
                                    "pcVersion": "4.26",
                                    "platform": "win",
                                    "previews": [
                                        {
                                            "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip"
                                }
                            ],
                            "name": "linux", "children": [
                                {
                                    "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw",
                                    "pluginVersion": 1,
                                    "pcVersion": "4.26",
                                    "platform": "linux",
                                    "previews": [
                                        {
                                            "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip"
                                }
                            ],
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "fy9h-dKw1", "children": [
        {
            "name": "4.26", "children": [
                {
                    "name": "1", "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "mac", "children": [
                                {
                                    "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw1",
                                    "pluginVersion": 1,
                                    "pcVersion": "4.26",
                                    "platform": "mac",
                                    "previews": [
                                        {
                                            "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip"
                                }
                            ],
                            "name": "windows", "children": [
                                {
                                    "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw1",
                                    "pluginVersion": 1,
                                    "pcVersion": "4.26",
                                    "platform": "win",
                                    "previews": [
                                        {
                                            "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip"
                                },

                            ],
                            "name": "linux", "children": [
                                {
                                    "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw1",
                                    "pluginVersion": 1,
                                    "pcVersion": "4.26",
                                    "platform": "linux",
                                    "previews": [
                                        {
                                            "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip"
                                }
                            ],
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "fy9h-dKw2", "children": [
        {
            "name": "4.26", "children": [
                {
                    "name": "1", "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "mac", "children": [
                                {
                                }
                            ],
                            "name": "windows", "children": [
                                {
                                    "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw2",
                                    "pluginVersion": 1,
                                    "pcVersion": "4.26",
                                    "platform": "win",
                                    "previews": [
                                        {
                                            "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip"
                                }
                            ],
                            "name": "linux", "children": [
                                {
                                }
                            ],
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

To clear out the confusion with the mess of this end result, all I want is to group them by their ***pluginId***, then by their ***pcVersion***, then by their ***pluginVersion***, and in end by their ***platform***. I'll just paste the format of end result:

```
[
{
    "name": "pluginId", "children": [
        {
            "name": "pcVersion", "children": [
                {
                    "name": "pluginVersion", "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "mac", "children": [
                                {
                                }
                            ],
                            "name": "windows", "children": [
                                {
                                }
                            ],
                            "name": "linux", "children": [
                                {
                                }
                            ],
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I found out about the [Lodash Library groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) method that is excellent. But I have to write a lot of bad loops for it and its too complicated.

I would really appreciate any hints or leads to solve it as I have been stuck on it for a lo\t of hours now and getting extremely frustrated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fairly compact example using nested `reduce()` calls and passing an array of keys describing the hierarchy to the inner `reduce()`. This allows you to refactor the original array in multiple ways simply by passing a different hierarchy array.

```js
const srcArr = [{ "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw", "pluginVersion": 1, "pcVersion": "4.26", "platform": "win", "previews": [{ "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg" }], "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip" }, { "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw", "pluginVersion": 1, "pcVersion": "4.26", "platform": "mac", "previews": [{ "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg" }], "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip" }, { "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw", "pluginVersion": 1, "pcVersion": "4.26", "platform": "linux", "previews": [{ "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg" }], "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip" }, { "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw1", "pluginVersion": 1, "pcVersion": "4.26", "platform": "win", "previews": [{ "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg" }], "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip" }, { "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw1", "pluginVersion": 1, "pcVersion": "4.26", "platform": "mac", "previews": [{ "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg" }], "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip" }, { "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw1", "pluginVersion": 1, "pcVersion": "4.26", "platform": "linux", "previews": [{ "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg" }], "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip" }, { "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw2", "pluginVersion": 1, "pcVersion": "4.26", "platform": "win", "previews": [{ "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg" }], "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip" }]

function refactorArray(arr, tree) {
  return arr.reduce((a, o) => {
    const inner = tree.reduce((ka, k) => {
      const match = ka.find(e => e.name === o[k]);
      if (match) {
        ka = match.children;
      } else {
        const n = { name: o[k], children: [] };
        ka.push(n);
        ka = n.children;
      }
      return ka;
    }, a);
    inner.push({ ...o });
    return a;
  }, []);
}

const tree1 = [
  'pluginId',
  'pcVersion',
  'pluginVersion',
  'platform'];

console.log(refactorArray(srcArr, tree1));
  
const tree2 = [
  'platform', 
  'pluginVersion'];

console.log(refactorArray(srcArr, tree2));
```

Or using `bind()` to create dedicated functions...

```js
const srcArr = [{ "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw", "pluginVersion": 1, "pcVersion": "4.26", "platform": "win", "previews": [{ "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg" }], "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip" }, { "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw", "pluginVersion": 1, "pcVersion": "4.26", "platform": "mac", "previews": [{ "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg" }], "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip" }, { "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw", "pluginVersion": 1, "pcVersion": "4.26", "platform": "linux", "previews": [{ "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg" }], "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip" }, { "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw1", "pluginVersion": 1, "pcVersion": "4.26", "platform": "win", "previews": [{ "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg" }], "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip" }, { "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw1", "pluginVersion": 1, "pcVersion": "4.26", "platform": "mac", "previews": [{ "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg" }], "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip" }, { "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw1", "pluginVersion": 1, "pcVersion": "4.26", "platform": "linux", "previews": [{ "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg" }], "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip" }, { "pluginId": "fy9h-dKw2", "pluginVersion": 1, "pcVersion": "4.26", "platform": "win", "previews": [{ "uri": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.jpg" }], "pluginUrl": "/e2d4-dKv/4.26/1/7f4bc5e9-3721-4f83-abd4-75792ae75e3d.zip" }]

function refactorArrayByBoundTree(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((a, o) => {
    const inner = this.reduce((ka, k) => {
      const match = ka.find(e => e.name === o[k]);
      if (match) {
        ka = match.children;
      } else {
        const n = { name: o[k], children: [] };
        ka.push(n);
        ka = n.children;
      }
      return ka;
    }, a);
    inner.push({ ...o });
    return a;
  }, []);
}

const tree1 = [
  'pluginId',
  'pcVersion',
  'pluginVersion',
  'platform'];

const refactorByTree1 = refactorArrayByBoundTree.bind(tree1);
console.log(refactorByTree1(srcArr));
  
const tree2 = [
  'platform', 
  'pluginVersion'];

const refactorByTree2 = refactorArrayByBoundTree.bind(tree2);
console.log(refactorByTree2(srcArr));
```

Comment: Thank you so so much @pilchard. It serves all my need with so much elegancy. You are a saint. Now I am having a bit difficulty understanding it as reduce is a new idea but its compactness has blew me away. I hope you won't mind me bothering you a couple of times about it in the comment section. Cheers!!!

Comment: Glad it works for you. Feel free to ask questions, I'm happy to help.